# How to find user can do clear cache?

Tags: android, notifications, background-process, ram

Hi I want to know when ever user can clean the cache i got notification from it.
i can try

```
protected void onStop() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
```

}
And Also Tried the to Extends Application also it is:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
 public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return activityVisible;
      }  

      public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;
      }

      public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;
      }

      private static boolean activityVisible;

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTerminate();
        Log.i("Terminate","terminate");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Terminate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

}
any One have to know idea for this problem give me the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a notify when user clear your cache.
Well the problem is simple, when the user clear the cache, it actually stop you prosses as well...
I can think about dirty solution involve file and shared preference, so you can see if your application is 'fresh install' and has file which indicate its not really new install, but the user deleted the cache. Anyway, its pretty dirty.  In my opinion, if user has deleted data, that's mean he don't want the data, don't leave traces.